# Can't install phpMyAdmin due to package dependency issue

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

When I run the command `sudo yum --enablerepo=epel install phpmyadmin` it returns the following package dependency error:

```
  Error: Package: php-mcrypt-5.3.3-5.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: php(api) = 20090626
           Installed: php-common-5.4.16-45.amzn2.0.6.x86_64 (@amzn2-core)
               php(api) = 20100412-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-43.amzn2.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php(api) = 20100412-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-43.amzn2.0.1.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php(api) = 20100412-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-43.amzn2.0.2.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php(api) = 20100412-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-43.amzn2.0.3.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php(api) = 20100412-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-43.amzn2.0.4.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php(api) = 20100412-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-45.amzn2.0.5.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php(api) = 20100412-64
Error: Package: php-mcrypt-5.3.3-5.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20090626
           Installed: php-common-5.4.16-45.amzn2.0.6.x86_64 (@amzn2-core)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-43.amzn2.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-43.amzn2.0.1.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-43.amzn2.0.2.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64


           Available: php-common-5.4.16-43.amzn2.0.3.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-43.amzn2.0.4.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-45.amzn2.0.5.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-64
Error: Package: php-tcpdf-6.2.26-1.el6.noarch (epel)
           Requires: php-tidy
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

What do I need to install to make myphpadmin able to download properly?

My php version is 5.4.16 (obviously) and if i run `rpm -q phpmyadmin` it says that the package is not installed.

Comment: And, Amazon Linux is not CentOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EPEL is not compatible with Amazon Linux, despite Amazon's bizarre insistence on advising people to add it to their Amazon Linux instances. It cannot be made compatible, and even if by some miracle you managed to install a package from EPEL, it would be very likely to not function.

If you require packages from EPEL, you must use a compatible Linux distribution, such as CentOS or RHEL.